# How to synchronize vkCmdCopyBufferToImage()?

Tags: vulkan

I need to render an image and copy it back to host. I issue the `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer()` from the render pass result to a host readable buffer right after the `vkCmdEndRenderPass()`, it seems to work, but I am worried the copy starts before the rendering is finished (or the image is transitioned).

Do I need to perform some kind of synchronization, or it is implicitly guaranteed the image will be transitioned to the needed `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL`, which happens at the end of the render pass, before the copy is initiated? In the specs, where is this sequence defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout of an image after the execution of a renderpass is explicitly specified by you, when you constructed that renderpass. This is specified by `VkAttachmentDescription::finalLayout` for the attached image.

As for synchronization, that again is specified by you at renderpass creation time. Subpasses can have external dependencies, where they depend on something that happens before the renderpass, or where they cause something after the renderpass to depend on them.

That being said, if you do not specify a subpass dependency for which the destination subpass is `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`, then an implicit dependency is created (one of the few times Vulkan does synchronization implicitly). This implicit dependency synchronizes color, depth, and input attachments from any command with the bottom of the pipe. However, because it does not specify any destination access forms in its mask, this is not useful and you should provide an explicit external dependency.

Also, using bottom of the pipe as the destination stage is pretty much *never* useful.

Comment: But `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer()` doesn't happen within the graphics pipeline, right? It belongs in the transfer pipeline. How to specify it must happen after "the bottom of the pipe" of the graphics pipeline? Or maybe, after `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT` (has the transition specified `VkAttachmentDescription::finalLayout` for the depth image already happened there?)

Comment: There is no "bottom of the 'graphics' pipe" stage; there is merely "bottom of ***the*** pipe" stage. The bottom of the pipe is the last stage for *all* action commands. And you don't want to sync with it anyway; you want to sync with the transfer pipeline stage. That's the stage that's accessing the data, so that's what you want the destination stage to be.

Comment: So, in my `VkSubpassDependency`, I need `srcSubpass = idx`, `dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`, `srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`, `dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT`, `srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT` and `dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT`?